# vuejs cannot read property save of undefined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a problem with my vue save method, I can't figure out how it's not properly defined. I use Laravel 5, VueJS 2, and webpack to compile it.

So in my app.js I have the following:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
import VueSweetAlert from 'vue-sweetalert';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueSweetAlert);

const router = new VueRouter({
    hashbang: false,
    history: true,
    linkActiveClass: 'active',
    mode: 'hash',
    saveScrollPosition: true,
    transitionOnLoad: true,
    routes: routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app')
```

In my createLocation.vue I have the following code:

```
methods:{
  onSubmit: function(e){
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = {
        name: self.vmName,
        street: self.vmStreet,
        street_number: self.vmStreetNumber,
        postal: self.vmPostal,
        city: self.vmCity,
        contactName: self.vmContactName,
        contactPhone: self.vmContactPhone,
        contactEmail: self.vmContactEmail,
        username: self.vmUsername,
        password: self.vmPassword
    };

    self.resource.get(formData).then((response) => {
        self.$swal('Gelukt', 'Location added!', 'success').then(function() {
            self.$route.router.go('/locations');
        });
    }, (response) => {
        var errorMessage = '';
        $.each(response.data, function(k, v) {
            errorMessage = errorMessage + v[0] + '<br/>';
        });
        self.$swal('Oops...', errorMessage, 'error');
    })
  }
}
```

Yet whenever I press the submit button I receive:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
```

But I got no idea why that's happening right now?
I have a similar get request on my dashboard which works perfectly, so I can confirm that vue router and vue resource are working just fine.

Comment: How does the template in `createLocation.vue` look?

Comment: Better yet, can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the part of your app that doesn't work?